# Access Denied to the source folder.. the source folder contains credential

Tags: c#, windows-services

**I found the solution on Codeproject**

I am Using Windows Service..
 Access Denied to the source folder.. the source folder contains credential ..

```
srcPath = @"\\IPAddress\XMLGateway\BOOutBox";
destPath = @"D:\LocalFolder\InBoxFolder\";
files = Directory.GetFiles(srcPath);
```

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a shared folder and make sure you give the appropriate permissions also in the sharing permissions (not only the regular permissions).

Answer (score 0):

That path looks like it's on a network share so I'm going to assume you have control over the service deployment and you are running under domain authentication.

You need to give permissions to the service to interact with that file. This is usually done by creating a user which the service will run under, and set the appropriate rights set on the remote machine.

Comment: I also used Impersonation but not userful

Comment: Do you have domain authentication? If not you need to create the same account on both machines.